# Using Rmagick, how can we get the image resolution (PPI or DPI), and dimensions in inches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

Im using Rmagick in my rails app with Carrierwave. I need to know how to get the resolution (PPI or DPI), and dimensions in inches. The `x_resolution` sometimes gives 0. So it's not reliable.

Comment: Could it be that the resolution is not defined for some images?
See: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22457

Comment: @gernberg I see.. Is it possible to calculate from the data we can get?

Comment: I think that's hard to do, if you get an image say 100px  x 100px, it's hard to know if its physical size is intended to be 1 inch x 1 inch, or 10 inches x 10 inches - which affects the PPI.
Why do you need the DPI / what do you use it for?

Comment: It's for a photo hosting website where people upload photos and sell them.

Comment: To get the dimension, instead of using `x_resolution` & `y_resolution`, use `columns` & `rows`. `width, height = img.columns, img.rows`

Comment: If you have the resolution you could easily calculate the maximum print sizes for a certain PPI/DPI. Trying to get the PPI/DPI from an image which doesn't contain that information does not make sense to me

Comment: @SharvyAhmed colums/rows does not return the DPI/PPI - it returns the pixel width/height, which could be used in order to calculate the DPI/PPI if one knows the physical size of the printed / displayed image.

Comment: @gernberg, Obviously it doesn't. I suggested to use columns and rows to get the dimension, not the resolution (PPI/DPI).